# In Android 11 i want to download some files into data directory of other App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage, android-11

```
var path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        
var RootDirectory = File("${path.absolutePath}/Android/data/com.any.app/files/")
```

I want to download an file at this location "(com.any.app)" this is not my app is is belongs to third party.

In android 10 or lower version of android I can to do this but in android 11 I can't.

Comment: You do not have read or write access to that directory. It is possible that you could gain access via `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Bear in mind that doing so may prevent you from distributing your app via the Play Store or other app distribution channels.

Comment: Can you tell why you would download a file in a directory that does belong to another app?